# Should I use Dictionary instead of XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, dictionary, xmldocument

I have an XML file which the (asp.net) application loads on startup, and every http request requests at least 50 items from it, by calling GetElementById. The class which handles it is static, so that XmlDocument.Load() is called just once. 
The XML file structure is very simple, where every node has only "ID" tag, and there is no hierarchy between the nodes (all of them are under the root node). A typical node is of the format:

`<txt id="OfficeEmail">bla@bla.com</txt>`

I was wondering if loading the XML content (~300 nodes) to a static dictionary will improve the performance when requesting for content. I can guess that once the XmlDocument is loaded, it caches the nodes in some efficient data structure, but could it be that there is a huge overhead over implement it with a dictionary?

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden When I'm debugging the code, it seems that it spends the most of it's time in the function that  finds nodes by Id. For example, every random execution pause will result in that function. No REAL analysis was made.

Comment: It would be searching all the nodes each time. It's probably a good idea to try and see if the dictionary improves performance.

Comment: It seems likely the dictionary would improve performance, there are probably multiple other ways to improve performance but without seeing the code ...

Comment: @Enigmativity That's my question exactly - what kind of data structure does XmlDocument hold? I would think there is some kind of optimization, and seeking a node by ID will result in some more efficient complexity than O(n)...

Comment: @Shay___ - There's nothing special about any of the elements/attributes in an XML document so it wouldn't automatically create an internal structure for fast searching. It would be linear.

Answer (score 2):

300 Nodes should hardly be a problem. but if every request makes 50 calls to the xmldocument, then you should measure the access times. and if it doesn't meet your bar, you could do:

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// read the xml file on start up populate the dictionary.

// after that, every Dictionary access will be O(1)
string value = values["OfficeEmail"];
```